# Postgis using contains and count even if answer is 0

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a problem with the count function...
I want to isolate all polygons laying beside G10 polygon and I want to count number of points (subway stations) in my polygons (neighborhoods) but i want to receive an answer even if that answer must be 0.

I used the following statement :

```
select a2.name, count(m.geom) 
from arr a1, arr a2, metro m 
where n1.code='G10' 
and ((st_touches(a1.geom, a2.geom)) or
(st_overlaps(a1.geom, a2.geom))) 
and ST_Contains(a2.geom, s.geom)
group by a2.name, m.geom
```

I know the problem lies with the `and ST_Contains(a2.geom, s.geom)` part of the where clause, but I do not now how to solve it!

Comment: What's `n1` and `s` in your query? How is `metro` connected to `arr`?

Comment: how, s is m I don't know why I wrote S. And metro are subway stations, and they are located in the districts of "arr". I want to select all the districts that are located next to the G10 district and count how many stations are in them... but there is one district with no stations and so it is not selected, i want it to be selected and appear with "0" for the nb of counts instead of not appearing at all !

Comment: please post your schema and update the query. What's `n1`?

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  a1.name, COUNT(a2.code)
FROM    arr a1
LEFT JOIN
        arr a2
ON      ST_Intersects(a1.geom, a2.geom)
WHERE   a1.code = 'G10'
```

I'm not including the other tables as you have obvious typos in your original query and it's not clear how should they be connected